# Pass string value to Powershell function

Tags: powershell

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm completely new to Powershell and have not been able to solve this yet.

I want to use Daniel Bohannon's [`Invoke-Obfuscation`](https://github.com/danielbohannon/Invoke-Obfuscation) to obfuscate large collection of Powershell scripts to use for machine learning purposes. The preferred use to obfuscate a script-file looks like:

`Invoke-Obfuscation -ScriptPath .\my_script.ps1 -Command 'String\2' -Quiet`

But this does not obfuscate the script as expected, and could be an issue with the tool. But I have found that calling the sub-functions directly works. To obfuscate a script literal I can do like following (assuming that I stand in the root folder of the tool):

```
Import-Module ./Invoke-Obfuscation.ps1
Import-Module ./Invoke-Obfuscation.psd1
Import-Module ./Out-CompressedCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedAsciiCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedBXORCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedBinaryCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedHexCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedOctalCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedSpecialCharOnlyCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-EncodedWhitespaceCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-ObfuscatedAst.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-ObfuscatedTokenCommand.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-PowerShellLauncher.ps1
Import-Module ./Out-SecureStringCommand.ps1

Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand {Write-Host 'Hello World!' -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host 'Obfuscation Rocks!' -ForegroundColor Green} 1
```

Which prints out the obfuscated script as expected. But instead of having the string literal, I would like to read the contents from the script instead to do something like:

```
$ConsoleCommand = Get-Content -Path '.\my_script.ps1' -Raw
Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand $ConsoleCommand 1
```

But this results in an error like the following:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find a provider with the name [...]
```

How do I pass the contents of a file to a function that accepts string input correctly in Powershell?

Comment: `Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand -Path .\myscript.ps1 1`

Comment: If you do `Get-Command Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand -Syntax` or `Get-Help Out-ObfuscatedStringCommand -Full` it'll show you which parameters it accepts :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm! Bad rookie mistake... Do you mind posting in an answer so I can accept it?